# AS400 jdbc connection pool problem

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, ibm-midrange, pool

I'm using AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource and AS400JDBCConnectionPool in order to create a connection pool inside my project.

this is my code for creating it:

```
         AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource();

        dataSource.setServerName(DEVELOP);
        dataSource.setUser(USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        dataSource.setDriver(DRIVER);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        dataSource.setLibraries("*LIBL");
        dataSource.setNaming(NAME);

        AS400JDBCConnectionPool systemi_jdbc_pool = new AS400JDBCConnectionPool(dataSource);
        systemi_jdbc_pool.setMaxLifetime(-1);
        systemi_jdbc_pool.setMaxConnections(4);
        systemi_jdbc_pool.fill(2);
```

My problem is that the connection is closed every 2-2.5 hours.. and I can't understand why , the max life time is set to -1 which means taht there is no limit on the time.

What could be the problem? how can I make the connection pool not to disconnect itseld?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution:
[Database Host Server Connections Drop after a Period of Inactivity](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas169cff834353af23e86256dde005cb32d)

Answer (score 0):

There is an IBM i-specific community at midrange.com. You can [try asking your question there](http://murl.me/java400).

If you get an answer there, maybe post the answer (or at least a link to the answer) here so others can find the answer as well.

Comment: Ya, sorry about that. My web server was "down" yesterday. I still haven't figured it out. You can try now.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [systemi_jdbc_pool.setCleanupInterval(miliseconds)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/info/rzahh/javadoc/index.html) to indicate to mantainance thread.

Comment: It would be better to show an example based on the link, with references, rather than just a link